# How to implement a CI/CD pipeline for Apache Beam/Dataflow classic templates (Python) & data pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-build

What is the best way to implement a CI/CD build process for Apache Beam/Dataflow classic templates & pipelines in Python? I have only found tutorials for this with Java that include artifact registry + Cloud Build, but rarely any in-depth tutorials for Python. I'd like to understand the "best-practice" way to develop pipelines in a Github repo and then having a CI/CD pipeline that automates staging template & kicking off job.

This Medium post was one of the more helpful high-level walkthroughs, but didn't dive in deep on getting all the tools to work together:

https://medium.com/posh-engineering/how-to-deploy-your-apache-beam-pipeline-in-google-cloud-dataflow-3b9fe431c7bb

Answer (score 0):

I use a beam/dataflow pipeline with a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. those are the steps that my CI/CD pipeline is following:

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I pull a `google/cloud-sdk` Docker image which create an environment with python3.8 and the essentials of gcloud tools.

After that I run the unit tests and the integration tests of my pipeline. Once succeeded, I try to build a flex template (in your case you want to build a classic template) with the `gcloud builds submit` command.

Also if you want to automatically quick the job after all this, you have 2 options:

- Either running the pipeline with a command line from the Docker container of your CI pipeline
- Or since you already created a template for your pipeline, you can trigger it using an HTTP request for example

Answer (score 0):

yes, for me, the Medium post actually covers most of it and helped me to build my CI pipeline as well.

These are the stages that I have:

- Infra - Terraform for the pre-requisite GCP infra
- Build - pip -r requirements.txt and anything else.
- Test - Unit, integration, end-to-end. I will implement performance tests with a sample of prod data later on.
- Security Checks - Secrets scanning, SAST
- SonarQube for SCA
- Deploy Template and Metadata (both Manual) to PoC, other environments and Prod. I use standard templates.
- Run Job (Manual) - actions to run job using the DirectRunner for quick testing, and also another job using the Dataflow runner using `gcloud dataflow jobs run ${JOB_NAME}...`.

For most steps, I used the python:3.10 image as the default (I ran into issues with installing the apache-beam dependency using Python 3.11), and google/cloud-sdk alpine for the gcloud steps.

There are other things we need to consider such as an action to stop a dataflow job and to rollback to a previously working dataflow template (need to upload multiple templates to GCS).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Today the recommended approach is to use `Flex Template` instead of classic template.

`Flex Templates` are based on a `Docker` image and a `Json` spec file from `GCS`.
It presents advantages over classic templates, check [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/dataflow-templates) :

- `Docker` image offers more flexibility
- All the needed dependencies can be pre-installed in the container
- Classic templates require using  `ValueProvider` for the job input arguments. Some IOs doesn't support `ValueProvider`
- Flex Templates doesn't require `ValueProvider`
- Classic templates have a static graph
- Flex Templates have a dynamic graph (example, uses a different input connector based on an input parameter)

With Flex Templates, whatever the SDK and language, the way to deploy and run the Dataflow is the same (based on `gcloud` commands).

I wrote a complete [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/ci-cd-for-dataflow-java-with-flex-templates-and-cloud-build-e3c584b8e564) on this topic to show in detail, how to deploy and run a `Dataflow` job with Flex Template and Cloud Build for Java/Python SDKs.

I also created a [video](https://youtu.be/8g5YdT-HbNI) to show in detail, how to deploy and run a `Dataflow` job with Flex Template and Java/Python SDKs with :

- `Cloud Build`
- `Gitlab CI`
- `GitHub Action`
- `Dagger IO`

The code is also available from my `Github` repositories :

- [Dataflow CI CD Java](https://github.com/tosun-si/dataflow-java-ci-cd)
- [Dataflow CI CD Python](https://github.com/tosun-si/dataflow-python-ci-cd)